# How to call command via ADB on android device using python?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, adb

I am writing automatic tests for android device using Appium and Python 3.x. I want to use python to call command adb shell screenrecord video.mp4 in order to record a video from the device.
Then it should keep recording for some time and kill the recording process.

It seems as shell doesn't "see" the argument with filename.

```
import subprocess
import time
import os

def record():
    timestamp = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H%M%S")
    command = ["adb", "shell","screenrecord","video%s.mp4" % timestamp]
    process = subprocess.Popen(command)
    time.sleep(5)
    process.kill()


subprocess.call('adb connect 192.168.2.128:5555', shell=True)
record()
subprocess.call('adb disconnect', shell=True)
```

I expected the code to record it and store in specified location (/sdcard/filename). 
Instead i get this output:

```
already connected to 192.168.2.128:5555
Must specify output file (see --help).
disconnected everything
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use `start_recording_screen()`, `stop_recording_screen()` to take screen record.

http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/recording-screen/start-recording-screen/
http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/recording-screen/stop-recording-screen/

Sample codes as below.

```
self.driver.start_recording_screen()

import time
time.sleep(5)

payload = self.driver.stop_recording_screen()
with open("cap.mp4", "wb") as fd:
    import base64
    fd.write(base64.b64decode(payload))
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use `execute_script('mobile:shell', data)` as below if you'd like to use adb shell.

```
data = {"command": "ls", "args": ["-l"]}
text = driver.execute_script('mobile:shell', data)
```

Also see
http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/mobile-command/